# How can I validate that a number entered into infopath is divisible by 4?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

Obviously it is for an HR form that only lets users enter increments of 4 or 8 for the value entered. So I figured one way may be is to take the inputted number, divide it by 4 and see if I get a whole number by using conditions.
If it is not divisible by 4 then a decimal would appear making it known it is not divisible by 4 with a return of a whole number.
I looked at all the functions and I can't find one that one would sort this out.

Comment: try validation in infopath, there you can use formulas `mod`.

Comment: I have mentioned that but I do not know how to code it to do as I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Add an additional field named “modValue” and set the default value to `number mod 4`.

   [image]
2. Remove the field from the form to make it as a hidden field.
3. Select the number field and add a Validation rule.

   [image]

Condition:

[image]

Comment: JoannaW_MSFT you are amazing!! You totally rock. Thank you!
Wishing you good karma!! :)